# Scaling problems with Scalable DP/SP library in Android app

Tags: android, scaling

I'm working on getting my app to display correctly across different devices, and for that i was recommended to use [Scalable DP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [Scalable SP](https://github.com/intuit/ssp). I then use a dimens.xml file which holds different keys that i use across the app, and those keys hold the reference to the libraries values like so:

```
<dimen name="large_digital_clock_size">@dimen/_25ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="large_digital_clock_date_size">@dimen/_15ssp</dimen>
```

Heres how i set it in code

```
clock.setTextSize(r.getDimension(R.dimen.large_digital_clock_size));
date.setTextSize(r.getDimension(R.dimen.large_digital_clock_date_size));
```

But it doesn't scale all that well in my cases. Take a look at these two screens which are from two different devices. and uses the above examples of xml and code

[image]

What options do i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem here was in how i apply the text size to the textview. This line (and the one for `date` ofcourse)

```
clock.setTextSize(r.getDimension(R.dimen.large_digital_clock_size));
```

Should be like this instead

```
clock.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX , (int)r.getDimension(R.dimen.large_digital_clock_size));
```

This fixed the issue for me.